# How to implement setRoot after logout?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I’m new to ionic and trying to make a login and logout flow ,

This is the structure

Login:

```
LoginPage => TabsPage
```

Logout:

```
TabsPage => LoginPage
```

I’m currently implementing logging out with `this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage)`
It sets the `LoginPage` as Root, But on clicking Hardware Back button , the `LoginPage` is dismissed and I can still see the `TabsPage` which is active in the background.

How do I solve this ? How do I remove the `TabsPage` entirely from the Nav ?

Comment: What happens if you use the `rootNav` from the `App` instance ([docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/app/App/)) like this `this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPage)`?

Comment: I get a warning saying `(getRootNav) is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Use getRootNavById instead.` And `getRootNavById` requires some String as input , and I am not able to figure out how to use it in the right way

Comment: Yes, as you can see in [this thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/getrootnav-deprecated-use-getrootnavbyid-whats-the-value-of-the-root-nav-id/96271/18) or [this github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-site/issues/1197) it's not very clear how `getRootNavById` should be used. A *workaround* would be `getNav() {    
    var navs = this._app.getRootNavs();
    if (navs && navs.length > 0) {
      return navs[0];
    }
    return this._app.getActiveNav('nav');
  }`

Comment: Still does not work. After I setRoot to `LoginPage` I am logging like this `console.log(this.navCtrl.getViews());` and I get `(2) [ViewController, ViewController]` , The `TabsPage` is not being removed from the stack for some reason ....

Comment: Could you please create a plunker, so I can take a look at the code?

Comment: I have switched from using `setRoot()`. Instead, I am directly changing the `rootPage` variable in  `app.component.ts` using RxJS' `ReplaySubject', and it works as expected now. Thank you for your solutions!

Comment: Could you please add that as the answer? In a few hours you'd be able to mark it as accepted, and that way we can close this issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were inconsistencies while using `this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage)` as it was causing the `TabsPage` to persist even after Logging out completely. Thus, I found a workaround by directly changing the `rootPage` variable in `app.component.ts` using RxJS `ReplaySubject`

I referenced this [Github Source](https://github.com/ionic-zone/ionic-auth-replaysubject) which has the implementation using RxJS

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
this.appCtrl.getRootNavs()[0].setRoot('LoginPage');
```

It works for me !